# MySQL connection error after docker removed

Tags: mysql, docker, visual-studio-code, connection

Error Message is:
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1130): Host 'host.docker.internal' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in E:\wamp64\www\FISH\test13\records.php on line 61
Error failed to connect to MySQL: Host 'host.docker.internal' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

On Windows 10, using VSCode, wamp, localhost, mysql
Was working fine, then I installed Docker Desktop on Windows
Was having trouble understanding Docker, so I uninstalled it from Control Panel ->Programs and Features.

Now when I return to localhost website, I get the error message (as above).

I have additionally removed any reference to 'docker' using regedit.
I removed all files '*docker*' from file system.
Rebooted.

root user has full access to database as confirmed in:
Server: MySQL:3306 »Database: mysql »Table: user“Users and global privileges”

Any ideas how to remove error message and get system working again?  Or do something to just move on from this error?

Comment: Can you post the relevant lines from records.php? Also, how is your database connection being configured? Can you post that, too?

Comment: I got this to work, but unfortunately forgot exactly what I did ;(